# MySQL query date with offset given

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

In MySQL I have a table node_weather:

```
mysql> desc node_weather;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           |     Extra                   |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| W_id               | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| temperature        | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| humidity           | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| time               | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
```

Now what I need to do is the following: for every two hours of the current day (00:00:00, 02:00:00, ..., 24:00:00) I want to get a temperature. Normally the query could be like that:

```
mysql> SELECT temperature
    -> FROM node_weather
    -> WHERE date(time) = DATE(NOW())
    -> AND TIME(time) IN ('00:00:00','02:00:00','04:00:00','06:00:00','08:00:00','10:00:00','12:00:00','14:00:00','16:00:00','18:00:00','20:00:00','22:00:00','24:00:00');
```

In the ideal case, I should get a result as 12 rows selected and everything would be fine. But there are two problems with it:

1. The table does not include the data for thw whole day, so for example the temperature for the time '24:00:00' is missing. In this case, I would like to return NULL.
2. The table sometimes record the data with the timestamp like '10:00:02' or '09:59:58', but not '10:00:00'. To resolve this case, I would like to add the offset to all the values in IN expression (something like that ('10:00:00' - offset, '10:00:00' + offset)) and it would select always just ONE value (no matter which one) from this range.

I know it is kind of awkard, but that is how my boss wants it. Thanks for help!

Comment: Would `GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) / 7200)` help?

Comment: May I know what is your idea? Just briefly is ok.

Comment: What does the time `24:00:00` represent? It's not normally a valid time since it would be the same as `00:00:00` of the next day.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you are completely right, I would therefore delete the last value from IN expression, but that does not solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: @Amadan I got your point by grouping the time every two hours, but that does not seem to work

Comment: Fix the offset to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a bit more precise than what I wrote in comments:

**EDIT**: Had a bug. Hopefully this doesn't.

```
SELECT
  time,
  deviation,
  hour,
  temperature
FROM (
  SELECT
    time,
    ROUND(HOUR(time) / 2) * 2 AS hour,
    IF(HOUR(time) % 2,
      3600 - MINUTE(time) * 60 - SECOND(time),
      MINUTE(time) * 60 + SECOND(time)
    ) AS deviation,
    temperature
  FROM node_weather
  WHERE DATE(time) = DATE(NOW())
  ORDER BY deviation ASC
) t
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY
  hour ASC
```

Basically, group on intervals like 09:00:00 - 10:59:59 (by rounding hour/2), then sort ascending by those intervals, and within the interval by the distance to the center of the interval (so we choose 10:00:00 over 09:00:00 or 10:59:59).